# Magento discount errors….one cent off

Tags: magento, discount

Of the 500 orders that we’ve had since we are testing , we got 4 or 5 case where the discount is showing like

9.99 instead of 10.00 
24.99 instead of 25.00 
49.99 instead of 50.00

it appears to be no outstanding correlation in regards to SKU number, brand, time of day or anything else I can detect. 
However, it appears to be product related. 
When I bought 1 yellow, 1 magenta and 2 black’s, it discounted my order $24.99 instead of $25. 
When I changed the quantity to 1 yellow, 2 magentas and 1 black and updated the cart, my discount changed to $25.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is in tax calculation (not sure, but you can try to solve it)

http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/?issue=12244
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/247201/#t346936

Comment: thanks

change the rounding function in the

app/code/core/Mage/core/Model/Store.php

from
return round($price, 2);
to
return round($price, 4);

works for me

Comment: would have been good to, at the time, quoted the relavent parts from the links as the first one just takes me to a white page, the other to the main page of the magento forums (and not the thread)